# General c# best practices

Tags: c#

Just a few questions regarding best practices in c#:

Any reason why I'd prefer to do:

```
var list = new List<string>();
object[] array = list.ToArray<object>();
comboBox.AddRange(array);
```

instead of:

```
var list = new List<string>();
comboBox.AddRange(list.ToArray<object>());
```

Also any reason why I'd prefer to do:

```
class myClass 
{
    private string _hello;

    public string Hello
    {
        get {return _hello;}
        set {_hello = value;}
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
class myClass 
{
    public string Hello;
}
```

Comment: Ask one question once unless they are related to each other, add your second question to a new question

Comment: There's not golden rule. The main point I'd advise you to follow is to target firstly readability (and thus maintenability) and consistency (always same constructs are easier to understand). That said, the second snippet's couple are not equivalent. Properties are not fields. Or did you meant auto properties (`public string Hello {get; set; }`)?

Comment: The first example is a matter of readability and preference and the second example does different things.

Comment: The first one is about debuggability. It's easy to watch the value of a variable in the debugger, difficult to watch the return value of a function. In that example it would be totally useless, but if `ToArray()` was a complex function with interesting results it would be different.

Comment: See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx for the latter part.

Comment: For your first example just use `comboBox.AddRange(list)`...

Comment: `For First Case:`
if you have `list.ToArray<object>()` usage later in your code, then its better to have it in an object, otherwise you are with with `comboBox.AddRange(list.ToArray<object>());`. Also it may be useful for objects implementing `IDisposable`, since you can later call their dispose method. *(Not in the above case though)*

Comment: @Servy I think `comboBox.AddRange(list)` wont work since `comboBox.AddRange` requires `Object[]` as parameter

Comment: No, and No, they all suck. Your first example doesn't do anything, I'd prefer `comboBox.AddRange(new object[0])` or better still, no code at all. Your second example should be `public string Hello { get; set; }`

Comment: @Servy that does not work and produces the following error: `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'object[]'`

Comment: @Jodrell this is an example, obviously my List<string> is populated...

Comment: @cogumel0, bad example then, ask the question you want answered and, one at a time.

Comment: @Jodrell also I believe you are assuming that this is in .NET 3.0+ where automatic properties were introduced.

Comment: @cogumel0, actually I'm assuming its .Net 4.5 until November, then I'll assume you mean .Net 4.5.1. Unless of course you specify otherwise in your question or tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example just creates an intermediate variable to hold the converted array - if you don't need the array later on then logically they're equivalent.

Your second question is a more significant difference.  Properties have many advantages over fields, including potential logic in the get/set accessors, binding to UI controls (most controls can bind to properties but not fields.

In general any *public* data members should be implemented as properties instead of fields.  *Non-public* data members can be implemented as either.

There are [lots of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+properties+vs+fields) on SO that answer your second question.

Comment: Don't forget binary compatibility...

Comment: Ok, understand that the first one is more about readability than anything else, but doesn't the first example end up taking more memory and time to process as it first needs to save the results of the operation onto a variable and then read the results of that variable?

Comment: @cogumel0 No - The CLR will create the memory either way.  In fact the compiler may even inline the call if you don't use the variable anywhere else.

Comment: @cogumel0 No, it does not.  It will almost certainly compile into the same code in either case.  The second example may very well end up creating a temporary variable, if the compiler/jitter choose to, it just won't be named, and in the fist case the temp variable can be omitted through some analysis that is performed.

Comment: @cogumel0 Variable names are only tags for us humans... The compiler will create (at the IL level) some space in the stack for the return value of the .ToArray(). If there is a backing variable it will attach some metainformation that will give that space a name (the name of the variable). This metainformation is lost at runtime (so in the end the code that is executed is the same in both cases)